# LASSO vs Pearson's for correlated variables

Tags: correlation, lasso

I have a classification problem that I am running predictive models. The response variable is categorical (3 classes) and all of the predictor variables are categorical. I ran pearson's correlation coefficient to find 5 of the 35 variables highly correlated with each other (cutoff >= 0.8). I also ran a LASSO regression for the purpose of variable selection. It doesn't shrink the 5 correlated variables to 0 as I thought this is what LASSO would do. Does anyone have insight on this? I would like to be able to explain why one method shows these are correlated variables while LASSO does not.

---

Here is the plot you asked for, however if I increase lambda I am going to lose many, almost all variables before shrinking those 5 to 0, whereas Pearson's and multi-collinearity tests results in only these 5 as highly collinear. Why the difference? They don't have to match. I just need to understand why there would be a difference.

[image]

Comment: How did you run Pearson correlation between categorical variables?

Comment: In R, I used the rcorr function in the Hmisc package. In SAS, I used proc corr. Both produced identical results.

Comment: I also ran a multi-collinearity and got a high VIF for those 5 variables.

Comment: Hi wisamb, Lasso is parameterized by a regularization coefficient $\lambda$. You report that lasso doesn't shrink the 5 correlated variables' regression coefficients to 0. For sufficiently large $\lambda$, lasso will shrink every single parameter to zero. Consequently, there are values of $\lambda$ for which those 5 variables are zero. The question is just how far along the trajectory are those parameters shrunk? If you can show us that plot, of the coefficient values of all variables for various $\lambda$ values, I think that will help clear things up :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for reporting that trajectory. There are two factors the Lasso regression is considering that pairwise Pearson is not. First, Lasso is also incorporating how the variables are correlated with the response y. It may be that the 5 highly correlated variables are also correlated with y and hold information that is valuable. Second, correlation between many variables. It may be that some of the variables with low pairwise pearsons are nevertheless highly correlated multidimensionally with several other parameters.

Comment: @JohnMadden Thanks for the insight! I need to look into multidimensional correlation of the variables some more. 4 of the 5 variables are indeed correlated with the response when running Pearson's. But since they are correlated with each other, wouldn't that mean only 1 is really useful?

Comment: @wisamb it means there is some redundancy, but that doesn't mean they don't provide any information. 0.8 correlation isn't really all that high from the perspective of colinearity. If all the remaining 20% is somewhat correlated with the response the variable can still be important.

Comment: @JohnMadden The cutoff is 0.8. Those variables are 0.95 to 0.99 correlated with each other. so it would be better to chose one, right?

Comment: @wisamb sure, at 99% correlation with a single other variable, I would be surprised to see Lasso pick that variable (unless that multidimensional correlations between other variables are all higher than that ;)).